# How to revert 6 commits ahead of upstream repo without breaking the balance ?

Tags: git, github

I made a bunch of code that produced couple of **files** under a git local repository. I, mainwhile, made some successful pull requests to the upstream repository on github.

The problem is that 30 commits later, I choose to delete the **files**. 
Comparing changes between my github repo with the upstream one, I found

> This branch is 6 commits ahead of UpStreamRepo:master.

but

> Showing 0 changed files with 0 additions and 0 deletions.

I don't want to make an empty pull request to synchronize my repo with the upstream one.

please how to fix this ? do you suggest that I *cancel* in a way the 6 commits ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me from your description that you can abandon your six local commits.  However, if you are certain that you do not need your six local commits that have not been pushed to the upstream repository, you could abandon them with a command of the form

`git reset --soft origin/master`

where `origin` represents the upstream repository.

Assuming that you are on branch `master` in your local repository, this resets your local branch pointer named `master` so that it points to the same commit that `origin/master` is at.